# Ionic 3 build app using electron cordova is not available

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, electron-builder

When I tried building a desktop app using electron, everything seems alright until I tried using '@ionic-native/file'. There was an error in console.log: 
*Native: tried accessing the File plugin but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator*;

How can I use plug-in above in ionic 3 desktop-app?

Please Help!!!

Comment: Could you add the command you're trying to build your app with?

Comment: It is: "npm run dev" or "electron ."

Comment: I had tried building my app by following this link: https://medium.com/@LohaniDamodar/lets-make-desktop-application-with-ionic-3-and-electron-44316f82901d